# Left Join Query On Laravel 5.3

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a query on my mySQL like this

```
select p.tgl_pesan, COALESCE(SUM(dp.jumlah), 0) as jumlah 
FROM pemesanan p 
LEFT JOIN detail_pemesanan dp ON p.id_pemesanan = dp.id_pemesanan 
WHERE p.tgl_pesan >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 day) 
GROUP BY p.tgl_pesan
```

And I tried to apply that query to my Laravel project like this

```
$data = DB::table('detail_pemesanan')
      ->leftJoin('pemesanan', 'detail_pemesanan.id_pemesanan', '=', 'pemesanan.id_pemesanan')
      ->select('pemesanan.tgl_pesan as tgl_pesan', DB::raw('SUM(detail_pemesanan.jumlah) as jumlah'))
      ->where('tgl_pesan', '>=', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 DAY)')
      ->groupBy('pemesanan.tgl_pesan')
      ->get();
```

But both of that show different results. Result on my Laravel project shows unexpected data like mySQL do, it shows more data from my interval. Is there anything wrong with my query on my Laravel project? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sql query will be:

```
 $data = DB::table('pemesanan as p')
      ->select('p.tgl_pesan', DB::raw('SUM(dp.jumlah) as jumlah'))
      ->leftJoin('detail_pemesanan as dp', 'p.id_pemesanan', '=', 
     'dp.id_pemesanan')
      ->whereRaw('p.tgl_pesan  >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 DAY)')
      ->groupBy('p.tgl_pesan')
      ->get();
```

Comment: it still show the same result like i've done, not like my mySQL query